# Unclear javascript/jquery programming pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am working on a web project where in the UI jsp pages. All the jquery/javascript methods are called via this pattern

```
A.b.c.d.methodName()
```

There are many .js files imported in the jsp page. So I have to search in Eclipse IDE 
to track the method js file.

In the js file which has an entirely different name not "A.b.c.d", the method is declared as

```
methodName: function()
{ // logic }
```

Can anyone tell me what is this style/pattern of using jquery.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to tag this with "Eclipse" since I have a feeling you're trying to get Eclipse to understand the nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript never looks for file names, the "namespacing" you see there is achieved by objects nested in each other as properties.

For example if you create an object like:

```
var A = {
    b: {
        c: {
            d: {
                methodName: function () {
                    console.log('What a nice method!');
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You can call it like this:

```
A.b.c.d.methodName();
```

Or you can add methods later in your code:

```
var irrelevantName = function () {
    console.log('This method is even nicer');
};

A.b.c.method2 = irrelevantName;
```

And call it by:

```
A.b.c.method2();
```

There is a much used extend method which has surfaced in lot of JavaScript frameworks, like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function%3aextend). This provides a way for safely extending an object while preserving original values if present.

You can use the jQuery one like:

```
$.extend(A.b.c.d, {
    method3: function () {
        console.log('An other nice method');
    }
});
```

And as you expect, it can be called as:

```
A.b.c.d.method3();
```

JavaScript libraries usually use namespacing: they create some kind of an object and populate it with all their methods. This way they [don't pollute the global namespace](http://marcofranssen.nl/writing-modular-javascript-without-polluting-the-global-namespace/) with their methods.

There are [a lot of ways](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) to add new properties to an object in JS, so it is not always obvious how a method is added to an object, but it is safe to say that file names have nothing to do with it.

For further reading on the subject, I would recommend [this google search](https://www.google.hu/search?q=namespacing%20in%20javascript). Basically any of the top 20 results should explain how namespaces are created and used in JavaScript.

On a footnote: I'm not sure how does the Eclipse tooling support JS, but as it is not a trivial problem (object structure can be modified on the fly) I would not be surprised if Eclipse had no understanding of JavaScript namespacing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has some sort of namespacing. The code could be using could be the [AMD](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) pattern? But again, if it's JSP it might be old....